# Chart.js 4.4 - Time unit for Timeseries

Tags: chart.js

A few months ago, I worked on a chart.js (version 4.2.1) chart with an x-axis of `timeseries` type and `week` as a unit.

```
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: "timeseries",
      time: {
        unit: "week"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And everything was fine.

[image]

Now I'm upgrading to the latest version (4.4.0), and the `unit` is no longer correct, each point is reported on the x-axis regardless of the unit I define.

[image]

I noticed weeks are correctly displayed with the `time` type, but I need the points to be evenly spread so I need to use `timeseries`.

Looking at chart.js documentation nothing seems to be changed from 4.2.1 to 4.4.0 in regards to this matter.

Am I missing something here? Or there is some kind of regression.

Comment: `timeseries` scale was updated in [4.3.2](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v4.3.2), see [#11388](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/11388). The method [_generate](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/scales/scale.timeseries.js#L119) is now overridden. This directly impacts the way ticks are built. Without knowing your data, I can only suggest to set ticks through `labels`, see [ticks.source](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#ticks-source).

Comment: @kikon, thanks for the explanation. What would you need to know about my data? It's dynamically pulled from a DB. Here an example `{"x":"2023-09-11T10:36:52.000Z","y":94.194}`.

Comment: I don't know which solution is more convenient - A) generating your own labels, B) filtering the existing timestamps with  [`ticks.callback`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#tick-configuration) or even C) restoring old (4.2.1) behaviour in a [custom scale](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html#new-axes). Any of these require experimenting with a real data example.

Comment: In the end, I went with option A, and I generated my own labels.